# Timing problems when publishing an initial pose to amcl

Tags: navigation, transform, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to publish a pose to the initial pose subscriber of amcl.
But I always get a transformation error although I tried different setups with adding/subtracting time.

`Failed to transform initial pose in time (Unable to lookup transform, cache is empty, when looking up transform from frame [/robot_5/base_link] to frame [/robot_5/map])`

`Time difference[s]: 0.001029`

`geometry_msgs::PoseWithCovarianceStamped initialPose;
initialPose.header.frame_id = global_frame_;
initialPose.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();// - ros::Duration(0.1);//triangle.laserm_A.stamp + ros::Duration(0.03);
initialPose.pose.pose.position.x = result.getX();
initialPose.pose.pose.position.y = result.getY();
initialPose.pose.pose.position.z = 0;

tf::Quaternion q = tf::createQuaternionFromYaw(theta);
geometry_msgs::Quaternion qMsg;
tf::quaternionTFToMsg(q, qMsg);
initialPose.pose.pose.orientation = qMsg;

initialPose.pose.covariance[6*0+0] = 0.5 * 0.5;
initialPose.pose.covariance[6*1+1] = 0.5 * 0.5;
initialPose.pose.covariance[6*5+5] = M_PI/12.0 * M_PI/12.0;
ROS_INFO("Setting pose: %.3f %.3f %.3f [frame=%s]", result.getX(), result.getY(), theta, global_frame_.c_str());

initial_pose_pub_.publish(initialPose);`

Then I tried the setup from rviz, with no setting a stamp at all.
Doesn't work, and I don't understand how that can work in rviz??

`geometry_msgs::PoseWithCovarianceStamped pose;
pose.header.frame_id = fixed_frame;
pose.pose.pose.position.x = x;
pose.pose.pose.position.y = y;

tf::Quaternion quat;
quat.setRPY(0.0, 0.0, theta);
tf::quaternionTFToMsg(quat,
                    pose.pose.pose.orientation);
pose.pose.covariance[6*0+0] = 0.5 * 0.5;
pose.pose.covariance[6*1+1] = 0.5 * 0.5;
pose.pose.covariance[6*5+5] = M_PI/12.0 * M_PI/12.0;
ROS_INFO("Setting pose: %.3f %.3f %.3f [frame=%s]", x, y, theta, fixed_frame.c_str());
pub_.publish(pose);`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/71119/timing-problems-when-publishing-an-initial-pose-to-amcl/) by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) on ROS Answers with karma: 496 on 2013-08-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Found out that this warning message also comes when you call initialpose from rviz.
So this warning gets always called when you set initial pose...

nasty...

---

Originally posted by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) with karma: 496 on 2013-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Aarif](https://answers.ros.org/users/20178/aarif/) on 2014-12-07**:
hi @madmax, is there a way to fix this??